# bat file to move folders and files from one location to another

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have used the following which worked only on moving files but folders could not be moved.

1. move /y "C:\Users\skamera\Desktop\test1*" "C:\Users\skamera\Desktop\test2\"

pause

2. move /y "C:\Users\skamera\Desktop\test1*.*" "C:\Users\skamera\Desktop\test2\"

pause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for folders:

```
FOR /D %a IN ("Source folder") DO (move /Y %a "Destination folder")
```

This works for files:

```
FOR %a IN ("Source folder") DO (move /Y %a "Destination folder")
move C:\Folder1 C:\Folder2\
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use windows native command:

```
MOVE [/Y | /-Y] [drive:][path]dirname1 dirname2
```

You can use `move /?`
call for more details.

So, in you case , the command would be:

```
move C:\Folder1 C:\Folder2\
```

Comment: This command does help moving all the folders within the directory, I need a command which can move both files and folders.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax:

```
move directory newDirectoryPath
```

Example: To move the directory ‘data’ to ‘D:\data\folder1\’

```
move data D:\data\folder1
```

This [Article](https://www.windows-commandline.com/move-files-directories/) May Help. It contains all about move and copy commands

Comment: Just so you know, we prefer link-only answers to be supplied as a comment here.